# 'borderBottomStyle : dashed' is not working in the react native. Can anyone suggest better way to do that?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

BorderBottomStyle is not working in the React native and as well as styled-components. BorderStyle is working fine. But BorderBottomStyle-dashed is not working and getting Component Exception.

```
<LocationText>BORDERBOTTOMSTYLE</LocationText>


LocationText = styled.Text`
margin-left:2%;
font-family:metropolisRegular;
font-size:20px;
padding-left:2px;
border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-bottom-width:2px;
border-bottom-style:dashed;
`;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzzUU.png

Any Better idea to style only the border Bottom with dashed in React native??

Answer (score 0):

In react-native, you can't style many components directly as this is not necessary. Often times the better approach is to put the component inside a container and then style the container.

If you're a beginner, then how you attach the styles to the "View" is something you can google and not important, but this is an example of just showing the one style attached inline.

```
<View style={{ border-bottom-style: "dashed"}}>
   <LocationText>BORDERBOTTOMSTYLE</LocationText>
</View>
```

Comment: If i put the borderBottomStyle in the View also im facing the same issue 
   `code` const View1 = styled.View`
    flex-direction:row;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:4%;
    align-items:center;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-style:dashed;
    `;
    const LocationText = styled.Text`
    margin-left:2%;
    font-family:metropolisRegular;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:2px;
    `;`code`
I want the Text Bottom Border style: dashed should be autogrowing based on the Text

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttxjj.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9e1s.jpg